# Nginx Server unable to access index.html when the file is inside two subdirectories

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a project folder. I can access my index.html directly but cannot access it from when its location is under 2 sub-directories. Is there any depth limitations.

Eg: My nginx root directory is: /home/user/projects

I can access the file directly

localhost/index.html

I can access it by
localhost/abc/index.html

But I cant access it from more depth
localhost/abc/assets/index.html

Please give a solution

Comment: I don't think there's a depth limitation. If there does, it should be way more deep than just two level sub-directory. Check your permissions of path and if you have put the file in the correct place. If the problem still exists, please provide your full config and how you access that file and what error do you get.

Comment: Agreed, please post your full config.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Replacing '\' to '/' works for me. So my root was C:\Projects\node, now it is C:/Projects/node